# Riemannian manifold as a metric space

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a reference to the following simple statement; it must be classical. (It is easy to proof, but I want to have a reference.)

> A metric space $X$ that corresponds to a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ completely determines the underlying smooth manifold $M$ and the metric tensor $g$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Isn't this the [Myers-Steenrod theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myers%E2%80%93Steenrod_theorem)? "If $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ are connected Riemannian manifolds and $f:(M,d_g)\to(N,d_h)$ is an isometry, then $f:(M,g)\to(N,h)$ is a smooth isometry"

Answer (score 14):

It was proven by Dick Palais.

> MR0088000 (19,451a) Reviewed Palais, Richard S. On the
>   differentiability of isometries. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 8 (1957),
>   805–807.
>   53.2X

[MathSciNet](https://mathscinet-ams-org.ucc.idm.oclc.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=135385&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=61&mx-pid=88000)

> @article {MR88000,
>       AUTHOR = {Palais, Richard S.},
>        TITLE = {On the differentiability of isometries},    JOURNAL = {Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.},   FJOURNAL = {Proceedings of the American
>   Mathematical Society},
>       VOLUME = {8},
>         YEAR = {1957},
>        PAGES = {805--807},
>         ISSN = {0002-9939},    MRCLASS = {53.2X},   MRNUMBER = {88000}, MRREVIEWER = {K. Krickeberg},
>          DOI = {10.2307/2033302},
>          URL = {https://doi-org.ucc.idm.oclc.org/10.2307/2033302}, }

According to Palais, if I read his paper correctly, Myers and Steenrod proved the differentiability of isometries but Palais obtained an explicit description of smooth functions on the manifold from the metric geometry.

Comment: A small precision: what Palais shows is that one can reconstruct canonically the riemannian metric from the distance. The theorem about isometries as stated by @Quarto Bendir is indeed due to Myers-Steenrod.

Comment: The theorems seem to be equivalent.